# Matlab .net interop class hierarchy issue

Tags: .net, matlab, types

As matlab is weak-typed language while C# is strong-type language, so their interop is not that natural as what I intent to be, thereby I have a little trouble in which I hope I can get some advice on it here.

In my case, I want to call one .NET library in matlab. That .NET library has lots of OO structures. My intention is that I do not want to change anything now from C# library side. I just add relative assembly into matlab.

For instance, in my .net library, I have

```
class A
{
     method1 //not static method
}

class B : A
{
     ...
}
```

In my matlab code, I retrieve one object of class B, e.g **b**, then I want to invoke this object's class A's method1. My natural coding behavior will be calling: ***b.method1(val);***.

However, Matlab will give me the below error which makes me unhappy:
**ERROR: No method 'method1' with matching signature found for class B**

I might post some of my study on this issue:

1. I do not do any OO programming in matlab side, all those OO classes reside in dll only. And I do not want to change anything from dll part as well.
2. I saw some posts that one can call superclass's method through subclass's class as: **func@superclass(val)**. However it does not apply for my case I assume.
3. I saw another posts on driver between mongo-matlab on github. I do not look through its details, and it might give me my answer, but I hope I can get some advices before I dive inside that code part.

Thanks

Comment: Check if everything is public - the class, the function, the super class, the super function, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey, yet after checking, that still does not work. My current solution is to build a driver from .NET side. Then I pass primitive matlab variables into .NET interface to construct my expected object in .NET.